# iOS build fails, produces wrong project name for Cordova 6.1.0

Tags: cordova, tfsbuild, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using vsts-cordova-tasks with on-premises TFS (2015 Update 1). After updating the Cordova CLI option in taco.json to 6.1.0 from 5.4.1, my builds are failing with errors like:

```
Cordova version set to 6.1.0 based on the contents of taco.json
Module cache at /Users/rob/.taco_home/node_modules
cordova@6.1.0 already installed.
Adding support plugin.
Processing res/native for ios
Queueing build for platform ios w/options: none
Processing res/native for ios
cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=ENOENT):/Users/rob/agent/_work/5/s/myapp/platforms/ios/myapp/config.xml
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/rob/agent/_work/5/s/myapp/platforms/ios/myapp/config.xml'
```

In the build agent source folder, under platforms/ios, instead of the expected `myapp` folder, there's a `HelloCordova` folder.

If I run `cordova remove platform ios`, `cordova platform add ios`, `cordova build` from terminal <strike>the expected folder under platforms/ios is generated and the build works as expected</strike>.

**Edit**: Using the Cordova CLI the correct folder is generated at first, but is then renamed to HelloCordova.

I guess the build task is not finding config.xml, which contains the correct app name, and it's falling back to HelloCordova? I've tried setting the working directory in the build definition and it appears to be correct. I can get the build to work again just by changing the target Cordova version in taco.json.

Build steps screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Did you get task from https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-cordova-tasks ? where do you find taco.json? Share your build steps screenshot here.

Comment: Yes, I set up the task following the instructions in the github repo. I updated to the current version (1.2.2) thinking that might help, but got the same result. taco.json is in the project folder (./myapp) alongside config.xml. All taco.json contains is `{ "cordova-cli": "5.4.1" }`. I've included a screenshot of the build steps above.

Comment: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from build errors in VS. I’m hoping to chat with folks like you who have encountered build errors and reached out to the community for troubleshooting. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. rsalva [at] Microsoft [dot] com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you go to platforms/ios/HelloCordova/config.xml, and check if you have HelloCordova inside. (try it out locally or on your build server)

looking at platformis/ios folder the name of the folder is correctly set at first, but after it's changed to HelloCordova.

```
Install complete for cordova-plugin-whitelist on ios.
1>  Executing "after_plugin_install"  hook for "cordova-plugin-whitelist" on ios.
1>  Executing "before_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Executing "before_build"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Searching PlatformJson files for differences between project vs. platform installed plugins
1>  No differences found between project and ios platform. Continuing...
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "ios"
1>  Wrote out iOS Bundle Identifier to "com.cct.driverapp"
1>  Wrote out iOS Bundle Version to "1.0.0"
1>  Set IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to "9".
1>  Wrote out iOS Product Name and updated XCode project file names from "SomeAppName" to "HelloCordova".
```

I know, that's not a real answer, so it can be deleted afterwards, but hopefully would shed some light as of now.

*Doesn't happen when creating a new project though.

**Workaround: Works nicely by downgrading to 6.0.0**

Comment: I think you're on to something - I'm actually getting the same "updated XCode project file names from "myapp" to "HelloCordova" line when I use the cordova CLI directly - so maybe this isn't related to vsts-cordova-tasks at all. Do you know what would cause the project to be renamed like that?

On the build server, in platforms/ios/HelloCordova/config.xml the `name` node is set to `HelloCordova`.

Comment: i have no idea on the issue, updated to cordova tools toupdate 7, and cli to 6.1.0 today. spent half-the-day trying to figure it out. downgraded to 6.0.0, the problem's gone. also in the config.xml you can probably find a real app name a bit below - so basically it has 2 <name></name> clauses. i'd bet on a bug during a merge